# Click event on an ListView not responding

Tags: android, listview, android-listview

i'm doing a custom ListView. I Have set a custom adapter whinch i pass in the Fragment that contain the ListView, but when i've try to set the click event on the items of the list, its not responding.

**This is the onCreateView function of the fragement**

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
     final View v = (View) inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_club, container, false);

    listView = (ListView) v.findViewById(R.id.list);

    c = new CustomListAdapter(this, clubList);
    listView.setAdapter(c);

    listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position,
                                long id) {

                Log.i("Infox", "KRIM");
            }
        });

    return v ;
}
```

**And this is my custom adapter :**

```
public class CustomListAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
private Fragment fragment;
private LayoutInflater inflater;
private List<Club> cItems;
ImageView img;
Context context;
ListView lv;

public CustomListAdapter(Fragment fragment, List<Club> cItems) {
    this.fragment = fragment;
    this.cItems = cItems;
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return cItems.size();
}

@Override
public Object getItem(int location) {
    return cItems.get(location);
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {
    return position;
}

public static Bitmap getBitmapFromURL(String src) {
    try {
        Log.e("src", src);
        URL url = new URL(src);
        HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
        connection.setDoInput(true);
        connection.connect();
        InputStream input = connection.getInputStream();
        Bitmap myBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(input);
        Log.e("Bitmap","returned");
        return myBitmap;
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        Log.e("Exception",e.getMessage());
        return null;
    }
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

    if (inflater == null) {
         context = fragment.getActivity();

        inflater = (LayoutInflater) LayoutInflater.from(context);
    }

    if (convertView == null)
        convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_row, null);

    img = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.thumbnail);
    TextView nomC = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.title);
    TextView slogan = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.slogan);
    TextView descipline = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.desc);
    Button join = (Button) convertView.findViewById(R.id.joinB);


    View v = (View) inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_club,parent,false);

    lv = (ListView) v.findViewById(R.id.list);

    // getting movie data for the row
    final Club m = cItems.get(position);


    //Set the button click event
    join.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {

            Toast.makeText(context,
                    m.getNomC(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    });

   /* lv.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position,
                                long id) {

            Log.i("Infox", "KRIM");
        }
    });*/


    // thumbnail image
    img.setImageBitmap(getBitmapFromURL(m.getThumbnailUrl()));

    // Nom du club
    nomC.setText(m.getNomC());

    // Slogan Club
    slogan.setText(m.getSlogan());

    //Disciplines des clubs
    descipline.setText(m.getDesc());


    return convertView;
}
```

}

PS: like you see in the commented code I’ve tried to do it in my custom adapter, but i think that a hopeless operation

Comment: You must disable click listener for you Button "joinB" to get onItemClickListiner working. :)

Comment: Why you are using the ListView inside adapter.

Comment: I can't do more than a button in Activity/Fragment ?

Comment: @sureshkumar its juste for testing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to achieve ItemClick as well as ButtonClick, then do the same to convertView as you did to join button. Impliment onClickListener to convertView.

```
convertView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {

        Log.i("Infox", "KRIM");
    }
});
```

Comment: And if i want to add an effect on click event ?

Comment: You want to add effect to what?

Comment: on the background item when it clicked !

Comment: You have to add custom effect to the convertView as you do to a button.

Answer (score 1):

You should delete onclick from adapter and after that you should use `setOnItemClickListener`